# Increase /tmp folder space using external drive

Tags: 12.04, tmp, tmpfs, customizer

Using **Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin, 32 bit on 6GB partition**

I don't have much space left on my HDD, so I installed ubuntu on a partition of just 6GB. Everything was working fine. I decided to have a custom ubuntu of my own, so I downloaded Ubuntu Customization Kit and installed it. On using UCK, I found out that it needs the /tmp folder to have at least 5 GB space, mine has just 200 MB.

I have a few external USB storage drives. Can I use them to increase my /tmp folder space? Please excuse me if my question is a stupid one. This is my first tryst with Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is possible, though I don't recommend it (see #2). You'll need to mount your external drive permanently on /tmp by editing the /etc/fstab file as seen [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Systemwide_Mounts). In between the change and the first new boot, you should reboot into a live environment and delete the contents of the old /tmp folder.
2. You allotted 1GB over the [minimum requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/minimum-hardware-reqts.html) for 12.04. You should not expect to be able to do any development, save many files, or install any real number of extra applications. To have the best experience with Ubuntu, you should install on a larger disk.

Comment: Thanx! Tried it out succesfully, but I havent been able to mount it permanently. Editing the fstab file gives a boot failure

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should format the USB storage to some file system that allows POSIX access permissions, like `ext4`. Check what your root partition is and format the external store to the same file system.

Then set up your USB to be mounted at boot by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=PUT-UUID-HERE               /mnt/mytmp               ext4            noatime         0 0
```

(Remember to add the UUID to the above line).

Then you could add another line as well, to bind the mount point to `/tmp`:

```
/mnt/mytmp               /tmp               none            bind         0 0
```

This will bind the mount point `/mnt/mytmp` to be available as `/tmp` as well.

**UPDATE:** You can find the UUID of your disk by looking at symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.

Comment: Thanx boss!:) bdw where will I get the UUID?

Comment: @user132528 See the update (you'll have to look inside `/dev/disk/by-uuid`).

Comment: @atilla The correct path is /etc/fstab, not /etc/fstba

Comment: @atilla I tried out your tweak, it resulted in a boot failure. I had to edit /etc/fstab in recovery mode. Then I could boot into Ubuntu.  Could you please recheck them? Then I shall try it out once again.

Comment: I didn't understand the second line. Could you explain please?

Comment: This looks wrong, I think the second line for `fstab` was meant to point to `/tmp` instead of `/mnt`.